# C# How do I make a program detect a specific answer?

Tags: c#

```
int age;
string name;

Console.WriteLine ("Hello!");

Console.WriteLine ("What is your name?");
name = Console.ReadLine();

if (name = Max H); // **error is here**
{
  Console.WriteLine ("Psst you're a nerd lmao");
}

else{
Console.WriteLine ("Hello, " + name );
}
```

Basically I want it so if there's a specific answer it'll give a different reply to the default answer.

> main.cs(13,16): error CS0103: The name 'Max H' does not exist in the
> current context =

The error I get.

Comment: `if (name == "Max H") { ... }` Note that there is no semicolon after the if. If you put a semicolon there then the code that follows is not part of the conditional.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Two</s>Three errors:

- Comparing needs a double =, so ==
- That "Max H" is a string constant, so must be in double quotes.
- After the `if`, you don't want a `;` as that ends the if. The next line will be executed always, except that the compiler will trip over that `else` (thanks RetiredNinja)

Comment: Three errors, there's a `;` at the end of the if.